# Закрепление кнопки на точной позиции изображения

Tags: javascript, css

возникла необходимость создать простой графический интерфейс к лабораторной работе. Один из пунктов - это описание прибора и его элементов (различный регуляторы, индикаторы и т.д.). Я решил добавить кнопки на само изображение прибора, точнее на его элементы.При нажатии на кнопку появляется описание соответствующего элемента. Положение кнопок отмерял в пикселях, чтобы посмотреть как будет всё выглядеть в итоге. На другом мониторе, естественно, кнопки поменяли своё положение.

[Результат моих "стараний"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJbvT.jpg)

Возможно ли как-то закрепить сами кнопки на изображении прибора так, чтобы при разном масштабе окна браузера и на мониторах с разной диагональю, кнопки оставались всегда на своих элементах прибора и меняли размер?

[Изображение прибора](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acgqR.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <h1>Описание прибора</h1>
            <img src="../img/main.png">
            <button class="btn1"></button>
            <button class="btn2"></button>
            <button class="btn3"></button>
            <button class="btn4"></button>
            <button class="btn5"></button>
            <button class="btn6"></button>
            <button class="btn7"></button>
            <button class="btn8"></button>
            <button class="btn9"></button>
            <button class="btn10"></button>
            <button class="btn11"></button>
        </div>

                <aside>
                <h2>Описание элементов</h2>
                <p id="description">В данном окне будет появляться описание каждого элемента, для этого нажмите на интересующий элемент.</p>
                </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
*{transition:.1s linear;}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: cambria;
  color: #240152;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {flex: 1;}
header {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #6F06CC;
  color: white;
}
.content-wrap {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: white;
}
.content-wrap h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.content-wrap img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
aside {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #FF9100;
}
footer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #D1D1D1;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  .main-content {display: flex;}
  .content-wrap {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  aside {width: 300px;}
}

#main-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.content-wrap .btn1, .btn2, .btn3, .btn4, .btn5, .btn6, .btn7, .btn8, .btn9, .btn10, .btn11, .btn12 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /* Exterior Shadow */
  inset 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), /* Top light Line */
  inset 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.2), /* Top Light Shadow */
  inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), /* Sides Light Shadow */
  inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); /* Dark Background */
  opacity: 0.6;
  outline: none;
}

.content-wrap .btn1 {
  top: 270px;
  left: 757px;
}

.content-wrap .btn2 {
  top: 278px;
  left: 944px;
}

.content-wrap .btn3 {
  top: 290px;
  left: 1120px;
}

.content-wrap .btn4 {
  top: 280px;
  left: 1334px;
}

.content-wrap .btn5 {
  top: 435px;
  left: 760px;
}

.content-wrap .btn6 {
  top: 445px;
  left: 860px;
}

.content-wrap .btn7 {
  top: 435px;
  left: 1197px;
}

.content-wrap .btn8 {
  top: 434px;
  left: 1358px;
}

.content-wrap .btn9 {
  top: 528px;
  left: 975px;
}

.content-wrap .btn10 {
  top: 594px;
  left: 1364px;
}

.content-wrap .btn11 {
  top: 620px;
  left: 338px;
}

.container .btn1:hover, .btn2:hover, .btn3:hover, .btn4:hover, .btn5:hover, .btn6:hover, .btn7:hover, .btn8:hover, .btn9:hover, .btn10:hover, .btn11:hover, .btn12:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  -moz-opacity:0.3;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну примерно так это делается :
Я применил этот эффект к двум кнопкам но click двум на SVG :

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 640 380" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g transform="translate(100 -129)">
  <g>
   <image x="-75" y="179" width="284" height="103" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/abremRN.png"/>
   <a target="_blank" xlink:href="http://yandex.ru">
    <ellipse cx="79" cy="233" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   </a>
   <a target="_blank" xlink:href="http://google.com">
    <ellipse cx="61" cy="231" rx="4" ry="4.1" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   </a>
   <ellipse cx="142" cy="232" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="171" cy="232" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="173" cy="261" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="145" cy="261" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="116" cy="260" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="98" cy="260" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="81" cy="260" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
   <ellipse cx="61" cy="262" rx="3.9" ry="3.5" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff0000;paint-order:markers stroke fill"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Старый добрый HTML-ный `<map>` предназначен именно для подобных вещей.

[Тыц](https://webref.ru/html/map)

Ну и жабоскриптик, который будет отрабатывать что именно нажато.